# await doesn't work and prints the same result multiple times in react-native

Tags: react-native, function, async-await

hi everyone i'm just learning react-native and i have a problem. When i execute an asynchronous method and then print in rendering the result, it's like the function doesn't finish. My code is:

```
export default class UserList extends Component {
constructor(){
    super(); 
    this.state={
      author_name: []
    }
}
async getPosts(){
    var sid=this.props.route.params.value_sid
    var did=this.props.route.params.value_did
    const utils=new Utils();
//now i resolve the promise after a network request
    const y=await utils.getPost(sid,did).then((responseJson) => {  
    const personArray = responseJson?.posts ?? [];
   personArray.map((data) => {
//i extract the authorName field from the json file that I read from the network and set state
    this.setState({
      author_name: [...this.state.author_name, data.authorName],
    })  
})
})
  }
render(){ 
    console.log("author name is: ",this.state.author_name)
}
```

console.log output is:

```
author name is:  ["Joe"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude", "Yuppie"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude", "Yuppie", "Ratatatatata55555"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude", "Yuppie", "Ratatatatata55555", "Bill"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude", "Yuppie", "Ratatatatata55555", "Bill", "Stacy"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude", "Yuppie", "Ratatatatata55555", "Bill", "Stacy", "Matt"]
author name is:  ["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude", "Yuppie", "Ratatatatata55555", "Bill", "Stacy", "Matt", "Jess"]
```

instead I want to have as a result only:

```
["Joe", "unnamed", "Jude", "Jude", "Yuppie", "Ratatatatata55555", "Bill", "Stacy", "Matt", "Jess"]
```

Wow can I do?i know that with await it waits for the method to finish to get the result but in my case, wait doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `setState` while mapping, call `setState` on the result of the map function:

```js
async getPosts(){
  var sid=this.props.route.params.value_sid
  var did=this.props.route.params.value_did
  const utils=new Utils();
  const responseJson = await utils.getPost(sid,did)
  const author_name = (responseJson?.posts ?? [])
    .map((data) => data.authorName)
  this.setState({author_name})
  }
```